# Increasing memory size of node.js doesn't take affect

Tags: javascript, node.js

**My use case**

- I have a Linux server which runs node.js 8 version
- The purpose of this node is to collect external workers array and compose them into 1 big response
- flushing the response to the network.

**My Problem**
I'm running at some point out of memory heap and my process breaks. This is the error I'm getting

> 1|proxy  | <--- Last few GCs --->
>   1|proxy  | [11552:0x4063010]   143107 ms: Scavenge 4416.2 (4694.3) -> 4401.6 (4694.3) MB, 4.0 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
>   1|proxy  | [11552:0x4063010]   143373 ms: Scavenge 4416.2 (4694.3) -> 4401.7 (4694.3) MB, 4.2 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
>   1|proxy  | [11552:0x4063010]   143639 ms: Scavenge 4416.2 (4694.3) -> 4401.6 (4694.3) MB, 4.1 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
>   1|proxy  | [11552:0x4063010]   143904 ms: Scavenge 4416.2 (4694.3) -> 4401.6 (4694.3) MB, 3.6 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
>   1|proxy  | <--- JS stacktrace --->
>   1|proxy  | ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>   1|proxy  | Security context: 0x31ced5525ee1 
>   1|proxy  |     1: _callee37$ [/StackData/bd/tools/proxy/server.js:~3482]
>      [pc=0x22e6d2a49018](this=0x1b549e48b339 ,_context37=0x325a9be822f1 )
>   1|proxy  |     3: tryCatch(aka tryCatch) [/StackData/bd/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65] [bytecode=0x170c5857ef81 offset=15](this=0x3b92b1582311
>   ,fn=0x325a9be82201 <...
>   **1|proxy  | 24-05 11:53:52.997: FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**

**What I tried so far**

- I verified using `process.memoryUsage()` what's my heap size before the error

  > memory at: {"rss":5161619456," **heapTotal":4920782848**,"heapUsed":4615629928,"external":10992199}
- I added to my start script this configuration `--max_old_space_size=8192` but it doesn't help, As can be seen from the previous log print, This is the full start command:
  `/usr/bin/pm2 --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS' -x -i 1 start node --node-args="--max_old_space_size=8192 -r babel-register" /StackData/bd/tools/proxy/proxy.js`
- Confirmed I'm using node 8.9.4 version using `node --version`
- I checked some SO answer, [this one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54594610/1031958), but I found no better ideas

Any ideas what else I can do?

Comment: can you post the command you run to start?

Comment: Thank you @Schwarz54 for your comment, I edit my question with more details including the full start command line

Comment: You realize that's almost 5GB of memory? That's a _lot_. I don't think adding more is what's going to help here, but rather figuring out how to reduce your memory usage.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes it's a lot... However, this is done on purpose reasons are beyond the scope of this question. I have a 64GB server why can't node use more than 4GB? The only purpose of this server is to collect the data and write it back to the caller.